Can I display the "To" field in Microsoft Outlook for Mac Inbox?
I'm using Microsoft Outlook for Mac version 16.84.2 and I have an email account with multiple distribution groups.
When someone sends me an email to one of the distribution groups, I receive an email in my Inbox where I see From, Subject, and Date.
Question - Is there any way to show the "To" field in the Inbox to show which distribution group it's being sent to? And is it possible filter each distribution group to a category or folder if possible to differentiate them? If this isn't possible in Outlook, is there another email client that will do this that's free?

I know I can open the email or view it's header to see it (see below), but I'd like to see the "To" field in the Inbox properties.

I've looked all around the settings and properties to see if there is a way to adjust the Inbox view, but I can't find anything.

What version of Outlook for Mac are you running? Is this a personal device or corporate owned and managed?

I'm running version 16.62 for Mac and it's a personal device, but why would that matter?

Settings change between versions, and controls on a personal device versus a corporate device will differ. Could you please add the product version to the question. This will help make your question better and more complete and help others seeing it better grasp the situation without having to read the comments down here: all bettering the odds of your getting a good answer.

Might've found something here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-views-in-outlook-for-mac-257d7104-5c90-4ee3-bad2-9935ab424c64

Columns work best when the reading pane is hidden or positioned below the item list, so select Organize > Reading Pane > Bottom or
Off.
Select View > Columns, and then click a column name. Columns in the
current view are identified with a check mark.

Other elements in that guide indicate you may be able to show the To field in a messages list, but I do not have Office/Outlook for Mac to confirm, so let me know if this works or if you've already tried this and "To" isn't a column you can choose.

hi. I appreciate teh post, but your link is for a much older version of Outlook.

Just for my own curiosity' sake: Do you not have the ability to change columns, or is there not a To column that can be added, or something else? That doc notes it's for "Office for Mac 365" which should always be the current build.

There's no way to change or add columns, or at least I can't find the way and I've looked throughout the entire app settings. I see some other recent posts that show MS removing this ability in the app redesign and update a couple of weeks ago. I htink I might be screwed. Others are talking about going back to previous versions.

You should start by updating. Version 16.62 is nearly 2 years old at this point. Current release is 16.84: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-for-mac

I updated to version 16.84.2. Still no ability to add columns in the inbox...
